# AtomicCAS for boolean

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, atomic

How could I write a function for Compare and Swap for boolean using atomic operation in CUDA?

I've tried to convert booleans to integers and use atomicCAS for integers.

```cpp
static __inline__ __device__ bool atomicCAS(bool *address, bool compare, bool val) {
    unsigned int* address_as_int = (unsigned int*)address; 
    return (bool)atomicCAS(address_as_int, (int)compare, (int)val);
  }

__global__ void update_matrix(bool* matrix, int* keys, int size, int nPoints)
{
    const unsigned int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;

    if (i >= nPoints)
       return;

        int u = keys[i];

    if (!atomicCAS(&matrix[u], false, true))
        atomicAdd(&size, 1);
}
```

I got this error:

```
Error   17  error : no instance of overloaded function "atomicCAS" matches the argument list
```

I could change bool* matrix to int* matrix, but matrix is a huge matrix and I want do save some global memory for other operations.

1. How do I implement atomicCAS for booleans?
2. Will the variable size return the number of trues in matrix if matrix starts with falses?

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62091548/atomiccas-for-bool-implementatin)

Comment: @RobertCrovella my question should be deleted due to <0 score. I think it's better if you write the correct answer here, isn't it?

Comment: @Kolay.Ne I'm not sure why your question was downvoted. It seems legitimate to me and properly documented. I'll work on an answer if time permits, but I think you are on the right track (i.e. the right solution) proposed already in your question.  I don't see any reason to delete your question.  Do as you wish, of course.