# atomicCAS for bool implementation

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to figure out is there a bug in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57444538/11248508) (now deleted) about the implementation of Cuda-like `atomicCAS` for `bool`s. The code from the answer (reformatted):

```
static __inline__ __device__ bool atomicCAS(bool *address, bool compare, bool val)
{
    unsigned long long addr = (unsigned long long)address;
    unsigned pos = addr & 7;  // byte position within the unsigned long long
    int *int_addr = (int *)(addr - pos);  // int-aligned address
    int old = *int_addr, assumed, ival;

    do
    {
        assumed = old;
        if(val)
            ival = old | (1 << (8 * pos));
        else
            ival = old & (~((0xFFU) << (8 * pos)));
        old = atomicCAS(int_addr, assumed, ival);
    } while(assumed != old);

    return (bool)(old & ((0xFFU) << (8 * pos)));
}
```

According to [the documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomiccas), `atomicCAS` should set `*address` to `(*address == compare ? val : *address)`, but in the implementation above `compare` argument is never used!

The code I use to reproduce the bug:

```
#include <cstdio>

// atomicCAS definition here

__device__ bool b;


__global__ void kernel()
{
    b = false;
    atomicCAS(&b, true, true); // `(b == true ? true : b)`, where b is false equals to false
    printf("%d\n", b); // b is false => expected output is 0
}


int main()
{
    kernel<<<1, 1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The expected output is 0, but the actual output is 1.

I have a suggestion about how to fix it but am not 100% sure it's thread-safe:

```
static __inline__ __device__ bool atomicCAS(bool *address, bool compare, bool val)
{
    unsigned long long addr = (unsigned long long)address;
    unsigned pos = addr & 3;  // byte position within the int
    int *int_addr = (int *)(addr - pos);  // int-aligned address
    int old = *int_addr, assumed, ival;

    do
    {
        if(*address != compare) // If we expected that bool to be different, then
            break; // stop trying to update it and just return it's current value

        assumed = old;
        if(val)
            ival = old | (1 << (8 * pos));
        else
            ival = old & (~((0xFFU) << (8 * pos)));
        old = atomicCAS(int_addr, assumed, ival);
    } while(assumed != old);

    return (bool)(old & ((0xFFU) << (8 * pos)));
}
```

My questions are

1. Is there a bug in the first code sample from the answer? If there is,
2. Does the last code sample fix it thread-safely?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  The implementation in the previous answer is not a proper `atomicCAS`. (I think it is basically doing `atomicExch`)

Comment: This proposal is not thread safe. Suppose the thread performing the atomic reads `*int_addr` into `old`.  Suppose at this read juncture, the `*address` value is not a match with `compare`.  Then suppose another thread modifies `*address` to make it match `compare`.  Then suppose this thread enters the `do` loop and reads `*address` and finds that it matches `compare`.  The thread will then proceed to use the `old` value for `assumed` which is no longer what we want.  The solution is to use the `assumed` (i.e.  `old`) value, and extract the necessary `bool` from it, for the `if` test.

Comment: @RobertCrovella wow, I see. This is perfect. Thank you

Comment: My [cuda-kat](https://github.com/eyalroz/cuda-kat/blob/master/src/kat/on_device/atomics.cuh) library implements a generic `kat::atomic::compare_and_swap()` for all simple integer types (and float and double) - with a generalization of the above technique where necessary. But - it's not yet sufficiently tested. I'll double-check my implementation against what you have here; and you might wish to consider using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many many thanks to @RobertCrovella; the first code sample does contain a bug, the second does fix it, but is not thread-safe (see question comments for details). The thread-safe fix:

```
static __inline__ __device__ bool atomicCAS(bool *address, bool compare, bool val)
{
    unsigned long long addr = (unsigned long long)address;
    unsigned pos = addr & 3;  // byte position within the int
    int *int_addr = (int *)(addr - pos);  // int-aligned address
    int old = *int_addr, assumed, ival;

    bool current_value;

    do
    {
        current_value = (bool)(old & ((0xFFU) << (8 * pos)));

        if(current_value != compare) // If we expected that bool to be different, then
            break; // stop trying to update it and just return it's current value

        assumed = old;
        if(val)
            ival = old | (1 << (8 * pos));
        else
            ival = old & (~((0xFFU) << (8 * pos)));
        old = atomicCAS(int_addr, assumed, ival);
    } while(assumed != old);

    return current_value;
}
```